# Nightly builds for Windows on Linux

Tags: linux, windows, continuous-integration, nightly-build

Is there a system I could implement on Linux(Debian) to have nightly builds from a github repository targeted to windows(.exe files)?

I know programs like CCNET and TeamCity but they are for windows.

Currently we use Visual Studio 2013 to build our project(We also support Code""Blocks but dont recommend it).

Answer (score 1):

This is how we do it:

1. Run Jenkins on Linux (Ubuntu)
2. Run build slaves on several WinXP systems to build the code, this can even be done on your own laptop for example. Of course you need to leave it on overnight.